# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.SportyShoe.Entity.Shoe

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to spring and spring boot. I tried to build a project by following
an example I found here : http://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-mvc-using-spring-boot2-jsp-jpa-hibernate5-mysql-example.html.

Here is my Application:

```
package com.SportyShoe;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.SportyShoe")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.SportyShoe.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SportyShoeApplication {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SportyShoeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my Entity:

```
package com.SportyShoe.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Shoe")
public class Shoe {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    

    @Column(name="colour")
    private String colour;
    
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    
    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    

}
```

Here is my Repository:

```
package com.SportyShoe.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.SportyShoe.Entity.Shoe;


@Repository
public interface  ShoeRepositories extends JpaRepository<Shoe, Integer>{

}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
package com.SportyShoe.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.SportyShoe.repositories.ShoeRepositories;

@Controller
public class ShoeController {
    
    @Autowired
    ShoeRepositories shoeRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/shoes")
    public String shoeList(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("shoes", shoeRepo.findAll());
         return "shoes";
    }

}
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

################### DataSource Configuration ##########################
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sporty_Shoes
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=MPword@123

################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When I reached this point in the example, it was written that running the Application will create the table in the database but all I got was an error as mentioned in the title.

What should do now to make it work?

Comment: Your entity scan is pointing to different package than your entity.
@EntityScan("com.netsurfingzone.*"), you might not need it as the entities are in sub package of main and have @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: @SapanVashishth, that was posted by mistake, I have already tried without  EntityScan annotation and also with the  EntityScan annotation with right package address (with * or without *, parent package or exact entity package does not help at all).

Comment: I suggest try with fresh project created from spring starter.  I tried with your code and it does create the table in db

Comment: If you are using spring boot 3.+, you'll encounter this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem was the version of Spring boot I used.

When I used 2.7.2 instead of 3.0.0(SnapShot) which I originally used it started working.

Answer (score 14):

I guess this comment is the key.

> When I used 2.7.2 instead of 3.0.0(SnapShot) which I originally used
> it started working.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) we realize the `Spring Boot JPA` module part of the `Spring Boot 3` release turned to work with [Jakarta Persistence API (JPA)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api) rather than with `javax.persistence.api`. Because of this even configuring properly the `Spring JPA` annotations like `@EntityScan` it does not find the entities.

When upgrading `Spring Boot` up to version 3, the `Persistence API` artifact must be also migrated.

For more context about this change, it's well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024749/851951) other SO thread.

Hope it helps anyone else!

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip! It is working after replace package form "javax" to "jakarta"!

Comment: Perfect information update. For anyone following the official Spring on using Spring Boot Rest - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ 
Be aware of the import changes to your model class. This will prevent the managed class exception.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was : i was using spring boot 3.0.8 but using javax.*
Replaved with jakarta.persistence.* API's and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have String ID in your `Shoe` class, but you've created an repository interface of `JpaRepository<Shoe, Integer>` instead of `JpaRepository<Shoe, String>`. So I suggest to define Integer ID in your `Shoe` class to match the repository.

Also the problem may be in a package definition - the javadoc suggests to use base package name like "com.SportyShoe", instead of "com.SportyShoe.*".
Also you may try to use type-safe entity scan like this:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Shoe.class)
```

or like this if you have multiple entities:

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Shoe.class, Lace.class})
```

Also try to remove `@EntityScan`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` - spring-boot tries to find entities and components in and under the package where you have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation by default (and jpa repositories, if you have a dependency on the classpath). These annotation may be used for extra configuration.
See information on this [in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.using-the-springbootapplication-annotation).